# Running a cross-domain node.js app on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, socket.io, cross-domain

Start with some sources:

**server -> main.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var sio = require('socket.io');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = sio.listen(server);

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 80, function (){
    var addr = server.address();
    console.log('App listening '+JSON.stringify(addr));
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log("user connected");

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});
```

**client -> index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
<!-- version2: <script src="http://localhost/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> -->
    <script src="http://foxclick.heroku.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
//version2: var socket = io('http://localhost');
      var socket = io('http://foxclick.heroku.com');
      $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
     });
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried every solution suggested do far including:

does nothing:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

crash server:

```
io.configure(function () {
  io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]);
  io.set("polling duration", 10);
});
```

lab feature not exists:

```
heroku labs:enable websockets
```

does nothing:

```
var io = sio.listen(server, { origins: '*:*' });
```

I already spent on it more than 6h. To be honest:

> client - server - status
>
> localhost - localhost - working
>
> localhost - heroku - not working
>
> heroku - heroku - not working
>
> heroku - localhost - working

Error from chrome console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load {heroku}/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1416257601410-0. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '{heroku}' is therefore not allowed access.

and

> MLHttpRequest cannot load {heroku}/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1416257732936-0. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '{localhost}' is therefore not allowed access.

Im desperated, I will try any solutions and ideas.

P.S. Git repo: https://github.com/Foxbond/heroku-socket-test

Edit:

The most weird thing is that I'm getting error about origin even running client and server on same host:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load {heroku}/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1416257601410-0. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '{heroku}' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: You need to configure Socket.io's allowed origins.  See their docs.

Comment: Already tried: `io.set('origins', 'http://{heroku}');`, `io.set("origins = *");`, `io.set("origins","*:*");`

Comment: And that gave you the same error?

Comment: Yes, `XMLHttpRequest cannot load {heroku}/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1416258754228-0. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '{heroku}' is therefore not allowed access. `

Comment: Try http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server#origins(v:string):server

Comment: `sio.origins()` already returns `*:*`